# have error for fill column with conditional mode of another columns

Tags: python, error-handling, mode

I have data base and i want calculate mode for some row.
when I want fill column with conditional mode of other columns and write code

jupyter notebook come back this error
Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception

```py
db['mode_process_time'] = db.groupby(['WID_COIL_HSMSL', 'TKS_COIL_HSMSL'])['method_3_process_time'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
```

i have this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 12020, in _reindex_for_setitem
> reindexed_value = value.reindex(index)._values
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 5094, in reindex
> return super().reindex(**kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5289, in reindex
> return self._reindex_axes(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5304, in _reindex_axes
> new_index, indexer = ax.reindex(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4434, in reindex
> target = self._wrap_reindex_result(target, indexer, preserve_names)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 2556, in _wrap_reindex_result
> target = MultiIndex.from_tuples(target)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 205, in new_meth
> return meth(self_or_cls, *args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 573, in from_tuples
> arrays = list(lib.tuples_to_object_array(tuples).T)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "pandas_libs\lib.pyx", line 2984, in pandas._libs.lib.tuples_to_object_array
> ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
> line 3505, in run_code
> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "C:\Users\1526\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7804\3007740805.py", line
> 8, in 
> db['mode_process_time'] = db.groupby(['WID_COIL_HSMSL', 'TKS_COIL_HSMSL'])['method_3_process_time'].agg(lambda x:
> pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
> ~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
> line 3980, in **setitem**
> self._set_item(key, value)   File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
> line 4174, in _set_item
> value = self._sanitize_column(value)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
> line 4912, in _sanitize_column
> return _reindex_for_setitem(Series(value), self.index)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
> line 12027, in _reindex_for_setitem
> raise TypeError( TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
> line 2102, in showtraceback
> stb = self.InteractiveTB.structured_traceback(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
> line 1310, in structured_traceback
> return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
> line 1199, in structured_traceback
> return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
> line 1071, in structured_traceback
> formatted_exceptions += self.format_exception_as_a_whole(etype, evalue, etb, lines_of_context,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
> line 953, in format_exception_as_a_whole
> self.get_records(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset) if etb else []
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
> line 1037, in get_records
> FIs.append(FrameInfo("Raw frame", filename, lineno, frame, code))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
> line 700, in **init**
> ix = inspect.getsourcelines(frame)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\inspect.py", line 1244, in
> getsourcelines
> lines, lnum = findsource(object)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\inspect.py", line 1081, in findsource
> raise OSError('could not get source code') OSError: could not get source code

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the input data and the matching expected output

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)